# How do you embed the camera display in a view on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How do you show the live camera feed in a subview within our main interface on the iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of good examples on google, or from the official Apple documentation:

[Apple iPhone Device Support](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedFeatures/AdvancedFeatures.html)

Hope fully this can point you in the right direction.  There are many forums too which have tutorials/examples on how to integrate the camera into an app.

Comment: how to embed from camera in uiimagepickercontroller in iphone xcode? Please help me out its urgent. Thanks in advance..

Comment: You could for instance try to follow the link in phaxians answer. It will point you to two sample projects that shows you exactly how to embed the camera using the UIImagePickerController.
If there are any specific questions regarding those samples just ask, but asking the exact same question sounding like you want somebody else to do your work doesn't bring you a long way.